Is a secondary resistance of 1.2 ohm OK in an inverter?
I have a Tripplite 750 A 12 V to 220 V inverter.
When I plug it in, the breaker trips.
I measured the secondary resistance for 220 V at 1.3 ohm. Is that normal?
The primary resistance for 12 V is 0 ohm.
As an inverter, it works fine. As a charger for the battery is has this problem. The component in the third photo seems to be damaged.  It looks like a capacitor.




Zero resistance on the primary is definitely not normal. Without knowing more about the device, I couldn't say whether 1.3 Ω on the secondary is normal or not, but that doesn't sound out of the realm of possibility.

How are you measuring the resistance? Zero ohms sounds perfectly normal for the low voltage winding of a transformer for some simple methods of measurement. I'm confused about what is, and is not, working.

Cannot charge the battery. When pluged in trips the breaker

If the varistor is blown up (as attached image shows), change it with a same voltage one? Varistors fail close. If the transformer's primary winding directly is 0 ohms, it might be odd and could be a short-circuit inside somewhere. But if the primary winding wire is really thick, the transformer's ESR of primary winding could be close to 0 ohms. Most DMMs can't measure such low resistance, so it can come out to be 0 ohms. But I don't think that'd be the case in your case. Also note that breakers can trip due to the inrush current a transformer takes. Especially if the breaker is B or Z-Type

(I think the component showing heat stress in the third image looks like a MOV. (And a MOV failed short is an excellent reason for any overcurrent protection to trip.))

I said "But I don't think that'd be the case in your case", but it looks like primary is the 12VAC side (I misread), which is a very thick flat copper wire. It should have a few hundreds of milliohms of resistance, and it's not unusual to have 0 ohms shown by DMMs of such transformers. A milliohm meter should give you the proper readings, but overall it's not going to be much useful for transformers other than detecting short-circuits.

The part that looks like a capacitor isn't a capacitor.  It is a metal oxide varistor (MOV.) MOVs often fail short circuit.
An MOV would be installed where the AC power comes into the device.  That would make sense in your situation.  The charger for the battery is powered from the AC input.  Near the MOV, you can see a smaller transformer that is part of an AC to DC step down power supply.
A damaged MOV would cause a short circuit on the AC line input.

Remove the MOV, then plug the device in and see if it works.
If it works, replace the MOV with a part with the same values as marked on the MOV.
If the circuit breaker still blows, something else is broken.

You can test the inverter without the MOV - plug it in, try it out, unplug it.  The MOV is there to catch voltage spikes.  If you only run it for a few minutes, it is unlikely that a voltage spike will occur and damage the rest of the circuit.  Do not run it for any longer than it takes to see that the breaker doesn't trip.  That increases the risk of a voltage spike damaging the rest of the power supply.

I do not think that the problem lies with the large transformer.  That transformer is to generate 220V from the low voltage from the battery.  If that transformer were damaged then you would not get 220VAC out.
